# Order from customer or admin?

Tags: magento2, admin, orders

How to tell from the admin whether an order was placed by customer or admin?

There is an `Origin` column, but it always says `Website`, no matter where it was placed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Orders placed via the stores, will have 'Placed from IP' in the order view page.

Orders placed via admin will not have 'Placed from IP' on the order view page.

This is same for M1 and M2.

Also available in sales_order table; if admin order, `remote_ip` will be empty.